# how to direct a sh script to run a python script?

Tags: python, linux, sh

I wrote a python script that calls two files to perform some calculations and asks for a name for the new file to place the calculation in so my code runs like this:

```
python code.py in_file1 in_file2 outfile
```

Now, I have several files that need the same calculation and their names only change by the last numbers, so I wanted to do a script that takes the different needed files in a folder performs the python script and name the outputs changing only the las number according to the given in_file1 (infield_2 actually does not change).

I tried something simple but is not working

```
#!/bin/bash
python code.py in_file[19]* infile_2 outfile[19]*
```

I get an error from the usage of python saying that usage: python code.py [-h] in in2 out unrecognized arguments

I know for sure that code.py works, I just wanted to spare to do it one file at a time. Thank you. I am really new in python and linux, appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Does `code.py` output something? Is it absolutely necessary to write the script in BASH? It can be written in Python too

Comment: Yes, it performs the calculations and outputs it in a file which name I choose as outfile, Is not necessary to do it in BASH, I just want to spare to do it one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```
import os

name = "in_file%d"
for i in range(1, 21):
    os.system("python code.py in_file{} in_file2 outfile{}".format(i, i))
```

This works as the following, with the `os` library calling the outputted strings:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 21):
...     "python code.py in_file{} in_file2 outfile{}".format(i, i)
... 
'python code.py in_file1 in_file2 outfile1'
'python code.py in_file2 in_file2 outfile2'
'python code.py in_file3 in_file2 outfile3'
'python code.py in_file4 in_file2 outfile4'
'python code.py in_file5 in_file2 outfile5'
'python code.py in_file6 in_file2 outfile6'
'python code.py in_file7 in_file2 outfile7'
'python code.py in_file8 in_file2 outfile8'
'python code.py in_file9 in_file2 outfile9'
'python code.py in_file10 in_file2 outfile10'
'python code.py in_file11 in_file2 outfile11'
'python code.py in_file12 in_file2 outfile12'
'python code.py in_file13 in_file2 outfile13'
'python code.py in_file14 in_file2 outfile14'
'python code.py in_file15 in_file2 outfile15'
'python code.py in_file16 in_file2 outfile16'
'python code.py in_file17 in_file2 outfile17'
'python code.py in_file18 in_file2 outfile18'
'python code.py in_file19 in_file2 outfile19'
'python code.py in_file20 in_file2 outfile20'
>>>
```

Comment: Exact copy of my answer, isn't it? :)

Comment: @ForceBru, nope. Open your eyes.

Comment: Thank you everybody :D it worked :D Your answers helped me a lot :)

Comment: @pepa if this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it? Click on the green check next to my answer (it gives **you** reputation too) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same in Python

```
from subprocess import call

fname="in_file{} infile2 outfile{}"
for x in xrange(1,11):
    d=call(["python","code.py",fname.format(x,x)])
    if d:
        print "Error executing: {}".format(d)
```

---

If you execute the following

```
fname="in_file{}"
for x in xrange(1,11):
    print ["python","code.py",fname.format(x)]
```

It will print the following

```
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file1']
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file2']
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file3']
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file4']
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file5']
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file6']
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file7']
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file8']
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file9']
['python', 'code.py', 'in_file10']
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell simply expands the wildcard `in_file[19]*` there and then into list of all matching files. There is no loop here. If you want a loop, you will need an explicit loop, something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in in_file[19]*; do
    python code.py "$file" infile_2 "out${file#in}"
done
```

where the variable `file` gets assigned to each matching file in turn, and the variable substitution `${var#prefix}` expands to the value of `var` with any string `prefix` removed from the beginning.

Incidentally, the `python` is redundant if you make `code.py` executable, and ensure it has a correct [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Note also that `[19]` matches a single character, so your wildcard matches any files whose name starts with `in_file1` or `in_file9` but no others. I'm speculating maybe that's not what you mean.